# Call a random array and its elements within another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hope I can describe this properly.

I've made a template HTML element to be filled up by info from an array when I run an onclick function. There will be different arrays so I've put them on a much bigger array. Now, what I was hoping to do, is to be able to call a random array off of the main Array then also be able to call the individual elements of the random array.

I tried creating an index randomizer and called on the arrays with it... it worked fine but you're bound to get the same set...

I've read and tried splicing, and the logic works fine. Console.logs shows that I got a random array, but when I try to pull out elements off the array I'm getting "undefined".

Here's a view of the code:

```
object00 = ["Cat", "Dog", "Cow", "Goat"];
object01 = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Manggo"];
.
.
.

mainArray = [object00, object01, . . .];

function next () {
  if(mainArray.length == 0) return;
  array = mainArray.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() *mainArray.length),1);
  console.log(array); //displays [Array (4)]
  console.log(array[1]); //displays undefined
}
```

I've read that spliced elements cannot be chained: is that the case?

Would appreciate it if anyone can explain to me what's going on and how I can work around it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to **choose** a random element in a random array? You don't "call" an array or an element in an array.

Comment: Also, try `console.log(array[0]);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(array); //displays [Array (4)]
```

If this happens your array must be array[0]
so to access a element you must do:

```
console.log(array[0][1]) //1. element
console.log(array[0][3]) //3. element
```

Or you can do this :

```
array = mainArray.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() *mainArray.length),1)[0]
```

Now you can access a element like this:

```
console.log(array[1]) //1. element
console.log(array[3]) //3. element
```

Answer (score 0):

Your splice return a subarray. in your case is subarray with length 1, which include an array. So actually you have a 2 dimensional array. to access the target array you should first get it (`array[0]`).

Anyway, I think better solution will be just randomly sort the `mainArray` then just iterate it from index `0` to `array.length-1`.

to randomize array use:

```
mainArray = mainArray.sort((a,b) => Math.random() - .5)
```

live example:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var shuffled = array.sort((a,b)=> Math.random()-.5)
console.log(shuffled)
```